# Function not printing after running

Tags: c, arrays, printf

```
*EDITED*
```

I fixed some issues but i'm still calling it wrong. Somehow when i don't declare with int the GetRand function more than once i get more error messages.

What i want as a final result is to print the array i created and also print the maximum and average of the values of it (only counting every number > -1).

I'm calling the maxavg() function wrong and i'm getting an error message "Error] expected identifier or '(' before '{' token" at the beginning of maxavg which i haven't been able to fix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <limits.h>

int GetRand(int min, int max);
int maxavg();

int main ()
{
int a[21][21], i , j, average, maximum;


for (i = 0; i < 21; i++)
{
    for ( j = 0; j < 21; j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = GetRand(0, 100);

        printf("%3d" , a[i][j]);
    }

        a[2][15] = -1;
        a[10][6] = -1;
        a[13][5] = -1;
        a[15][17] = -1;
        a[17][17] = -1;
        a[19][6] = -1;

    printf("\n");

}


average = maxavg();
maximum = maxavg();


printf("average = %d \n maximum = %d", average, maximum);




return 0;

}



// random seed
int GetRand(int min, int max);
int get () 
{
int i, r;
for (i = 0; i < 21; i++)
 {
    r = GetRand(0, 100);
    printf("Your number is %d \n", r);
}
 return(0);
 }

int GetRand(int min, int max)
{
static int Init = 0;
int rc;             

if (Init == 0)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    Init = 1;
}

rc = (rand() % (max - min +1) +min);

return (rc);
}




// max and average

int maxavg();
{

int max=INT_MIN, sum=0, count=0, avg, n, m, current;

current = a[i][j];
avg = sum/count;

for(n = 0; n < 21; n++){
    for(m =0; m < 21; m++){
        if(current > -1){
            sum = sum + current;
            count = count + 1;
            if(current > max){
                max = current;
            }
        }

    }
}


return(0);

}
```

Comment: You have created a function for computing statistics for your array, but you never call it, so it won't print anything.  That function is broken, by the way, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Why are you setting `a[2][15]`, etc. every time through the loop? If you want to replace the random number with those values, do it after the loop.

Comment: `int maxavg();` means a function **declaration**, but you're then trying to **define** it, so you should remove the `;`. Also, `maxavg` now always returns 0, not your calculated maximum and average. And there is no `a` in the scope of this function (or even `i` or `j`). You need to pass the array you create in `main` as a parameter to `maxavg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program will only print the elements of the array `a` in the for-loop in `main`. Apart from `GetRand`, no other function is called, so `get` and `maxavg` are never executed, despite being defined. So yes, you should first of all call it from `main` if you want to see what it does.

There is also a big problem with the logic of your `maxavg` function though.
Where is the array you're presuming to iterate over? You haven't passed any parameter to `maxavg` (nor declared and set a local variable). It looks like you're expecting `current` to contain these array element values, but the reality is you've never set the value of this variable to anything. You should be using the `i` and `j` variables as indexes into the array you should add, as in `arr[i][j]`.

A few other notes:

- You really should be setting `a[2][15]`, `a[10][6]` and so on after the loop has finished, not in every single iteration.
- You've declared `GetRand` twice.
- `maxavg` returns an `int`, yet there is no `return` statement in your function ("control reaches end of non-void function").

Comment: Do you mean before main and then the function itself?  When i delete "int" before maxavg i get more error messages somehow.

Comment: The syntax for a function definition is `return_type function_name(param_type param_name, ...) { /* function body */}`. If the function doesn't return anything, then its return type is `void`.